# Should I prune lavender on a cold/wet day in Spring?

Tags: flowers, pruning, perennials, optimal-conditions, cold-weather

I'd like to prune lavender for the spring season.

Today it's a cold and wet day (2 to 7 degrees Celsius and some rainfall, in Europe), the weather forecast says next week will be sunny, but I'll have less time for gardening during the week.

So my question is this: how much attention should one pay to local temperature and weather conditions when pruning plants. I imagine for "them" this is like surgery and they may be in a better position to recover and thrive if it is performed under mild conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to prune in the cold, then damp is good (it prevents drying). Go ahead and prune the lavender. It won't be harmed by it at all, this time of year.